# Do not remove a specific DataFrame

Tags: r

I'm working with many `DF` (over 30),however I want to exclude all but one specific. Example of my `DF`'s:

```
DF1

XY2

WWQ3

PIUG4

AZZ5

TEST6

DF7

MBYRZ8

DF9

DF10
```

So I want to delete 9 `DF`'s except `DF 7`. How do I keep only `DF7`?

Comment: Usually I use rm (list = ls ()) to delete all objects. But in this moment I want to delete all but the example (DF7)

Comment: Ok, I updated the post with `eapply` to selectively remove only the data.frame objects that are not 'DF7'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding @GKi answer (accept his, not mine)

```
df1 <- data.frame(V1=c(1,2,3,4),V2=c(5,6,7,8))
df2 <- data.frame(V1=c(1,2,3,4),V2=c(5,6,7,8))
df3 <- data.frame(V1=c(1,2,3,4),V2=c(5,6,7,8))
df4 <- data.frame(V1=c(1,2,3,4),V2=c(5,6,7,8))

> ls()
[1] "df1" "df2" "df3" "df4"

>ls()[!ls() %in% "df2"]
[1] "df1" "df3" "df4"

> rm(list=ls()[!ls() %in% "df2"])
> ls()
[1] "df2"
```

Answer (score 3):

One option is to place the datasets into a `list` with `mget` after getting all the `data.frame` objects from the global env with `eapply`.  Then, we can do the skipping easily and do the modification, update the list element

```
v1 <- unlist(eapply(.GlobalEnv, is.data.frame))
lst1 <- mget(names(v1)[v1])
lst1[["DF7"]] <- lst1[["DF7"]] * 5
```

---

If we want to `rm` the object from the global environment

```
rm(list = setdiff(names(v1)[v1], "DF7"))
```

-testing

```
names(v1)[v1]
#[1] "df" "df1"        "mydf"       "test_set"   "train_set" 

rm(list = setdiff(names(v1)[v1], "df1"))
```

again checking

```
v2 <-  unlist(eapply(.GlobalEnv, is.data.frame))
names(v2)[v2]
#[1] "df1"
```

Comment: I will edit and specify better. DF names will not always have the same pattern

Comment: Why you used (* 5)?

Comment: @BrunoAvila It was just an example to show that we can do transformations selectively

Comment: unfortunately the DFs were not excluded. They remained in the Environment.

Comment: @BrunoAvila Sorry, a typo, it should be `rm(list = setdiff(names(v1)[v1], "DF7"))` (updated the output)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ls` and `setdiff` to remove all but not `DF7`.

```
rm(list=setdiff(ls(), "DF7"))
```